# Определить счёт теннисного матча

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно определить по строке, что это счет первого сета теннисного матча.
 Вот паттерн:

```
private static final String FIRST_SET_PATTERN = "^0:0\\((6:6|[0-5]:[0-5])\\)\\(((@0|@15|@30|@40:0|15|30|40)|(0|15|30|40:0@|15@|30@|40@))";
```

А вот строки, которые должны подходить под этот паттерн:

```
String[]
{
    "0:0(1:1)(@0:0)",
    "0:0(0:0)(15:15@)",
    "0:0(1:0)(@40:0)",
    "0:0(0:5)(30:15@)", 
    "0:0(5:5)(0:30@)",
    "0:0(3:5)(@30:15)", 
    "0:0(6:6)(0:0@)",
    "0:0(6:6)(40:40@)"
};
```

На этом этапе все работает, но в паттерне нет проверки закрывающей скобки, которой должна заканчиваться строка. Если в конце паттерна добавляю `\\)$` то это не работает. В регулярках плаваю, поэтому прошу подсказки.

Comment: Так же буду признателен за оптимизацию

Comment: Разобрался сам вроде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю

```
String pat = "^0:0\\((6:6|[0-5]:[0-5])\\)\\(@?([43]?0|15):([43]?0|15)@?\\)$";
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/Cb7iMH/1)

При использовании метода `Matcher#matches()` "якоря" `^` и `$` можно опустить.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `0:0` - подстрока `0:0`
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `(6:6|[0-5]:[0-5])` - `6:6` или цифры от 0 до 5, двоеточие и цифры от 0 до 5
- `\)\(` - подстрока `)(`
- `@?` - 1 или 0 знаков `@`
- `([43]?0|15)` - `4`, `3` (опционально), а  потом `0` -ИЛИ- `15`
- `:` - двоеточие
- `([43]?0|15)` - `4`, `3` (опционально), а  потом `0` -ИЛИ- `15`
- `@?` - 1 или 0 знаков `@`
- `\\)` - знак `)`
- `$` - конец текста.

Comment: А эта регулярка находит только полное совпадение. Для нахождения только в начале строки удалите `$`.

Comment: пардон, нормально работает